# Having trouble inputting files into plink

Tags: genetics, vcf-variant-call-format

I am having problems simply inputting files into plink (I am quite new to coding). At the moment, I am simply trying to make a bed file in plink

I have recently run a HD SNP Array to look for copy number variation. All seemed to be going okay until I tried to input the ped and map files into plink. Initially I was receiving error messages of "half-missing calls in .ped file" yet when I checked the file lines, I couldn't see any problem i.e. at the location noted in the error message, there was a 0/0.

After many attempts to get around this, I was advised to try the files in vcf format and input these into plink. I am now getting a different error message stating :

> invalid variant bp coordinate on line 533890 of .vcf file

I have searched all over the internet and have not been able to find any solutions

This is the line of code I'm trying to run:

```sh
/data1/_software/plink/plink --vcf RBV_MNEc670_BPW_NoPQC.vcf --make-bed --out SNP_array_bed --horse --no-pheno --no-sex --no-parents --no-fid
```

I know that I want to make a bed file, and I'm fairly certain I'm not making any syntax errors. My current error message reads:

> 257665 MB RAM detected; reserving 128832 MB for main workspace
>   --vcf: 533k variants complete.
>   Error: Invalid variant bp coordinate on line 533890 of .vcf file.

Any help will be very gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has come to my question with a similar problem, I have finally solved my issue.

For some reason, exporting the vcf file created a weird issue in that, some for of the uncalled variants, instead of having `0/0` they had `./.`.

For example:

```
0   AX-102948208    N   N   .   PASS    UNKNOWNPOSITION;CR=100;ConversionType=PolyHighResolution    GT  ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./. ./.
```

I still don't know why this happened, but a quick use of the grep command removed these variants and I was successfully able to input the file into `plink`.

Hope this helps someone else from struggling.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using one more option named `--vcf-half-call <mode>` to deal with Error: Half-missing call in .ped file at variant.

Please check more information in [this link](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/input)